# How to get style attributes and line number of htm elements?

Tags: php, css, attributes, web-crawler

I have tried the following, but its not working correctly, it gives me all kind of tags, also tags without a style attribute.

1. Load website with curl()
2. Add html body from curl to variable named: `$bodyhtml`
3. Use preg_match_all to find all the style attributes on the page, but not working as expected.

My preg_match_all:

```
preg_mathc_all = preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', $bodyhtml, $matches);
```

What would be the best way to get the value of style attributes and if possible the line in the document where it is found?

Comment: simple. don't use regexes. [DOM](http://php.net/dom) exists for a reason, and this is it...

Comment: Rather than use regular expressions why not use `DOMDocument` and possibly also `DOMXPath` to do this - probably much simpler

Comment: Thanks gonna look that way instead. Do u know how to get the line of the element in the document by DOM? And is it possible at all. ?

Comment: There is not, afaik, a built-in function to do that straight off but it should be fairly easy to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help so far. 
I ended up using DOM and is working just as it should :) Thanks!

I have been trying to find a function/class which could find the line in a document either be DOM or an HTML string.

But so far no luck.

Anybody got a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Having said "it should be fairly easy to accomplish" I thought I'd have a try and now have to admit that it is not quite as straightforward as I had initially imagined it might be. The following gets close and someone ( the OP ) might wish to take some time to study it and see where it can be improved.

There are little in the way of notes/comments so I'll probably get voted down as a result but I leave it here in the hope the op can make it more accurate ( it's not far off! )

```
$url='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34998468/how-to-get-style-attributes-and-line-number-of-htm-elements#34998468';
$tmp=tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'html' );
file_put_contents( $tmp, file_get_contents( $url ) );

$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $tmp );

$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );/* the xpath query could be improved */
$col=$xp->query( '//*[@style]', $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0) );

if( $col ){
    $data=array();
    /* iterate through nodes found by xpath query */
    foreach( $col as $node ){
        $tag=$node->tagName;
        $value=$node->nodeValue;
        $style=$node->getAttribute('style');
        /* create array for later use */
        $data[]=(object)array( 'tag'=>$tag, 'style'=>$style, 'html'=>trim( strip_tags( $value ) ) );
    }

    /* connect to the new file */
    $spl=new SplFileObject( $tmp );

    /* iterate through array found from xpath */
    foreach( $data as $key => $obj ){
        $str=$obj->html;
        $i=1;

        if( !empty( $str ) && strlen( $str ) > 1 ){/* ignore empty strings */
            $spl->fseek( 0 );

            while( !$spl->eof() ) {/* read the html source file line by line + make matches */
                if( stristr( $spl->fgetss(), $str ) ) {
                    echo 'line: '.$i.', tag: '.$obj->tag.', html:'.$str.', style:'.$obj->style.BR;
                    break;  
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
@unlink( $tmp );
$dom = $xp = $col = $spl = $tmp = null;
```